# Determine the Galois groups of each of these polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

$x^3 - 5$.

Here the minimal polynomial is $x = \sqrt[3]{5}$, so the Galois group would be $G(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, i) / \mathbb{Q})$. There are 2 autormorphisms.

$x^5 + 1$

This one I am unsure of.

$x^8 - 1$

The Galois group would be $G(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{1}, i) / \mathbb{Q})$. There is only one automorphism.

I am a little unsure but here is my educated guesses.

Comment: It seems to be you believe that you have to add $\;i\;$ every time to get a Galois Extension. This is far from being true, at least in the two you did so above. For the first one try better a root of unity of order three, and for the last one of order four...

Comment: The only reason I added the $i$ in is because their are complex solutions to the polynomial.

Comment: So what, @user105998 ? It still may be wrong. For example, the splitting field of $\;x^3-5\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ **must** contain the element $\;e^{2\pi i/3}\sqrt[3] 5\;$ . Do you think this element belongs to $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]5,i)\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

In the 1st case, $G=Gal \left( \mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt[3]{5}) : \mathbb{Q}\right) $ has order 6 and a non-Galois subextension, $\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt[3]{5})$, corresponding to a non normal subgroup of order 2 (by the Galois Correspondence Theorem), then $G=S_3$.

To find the Galois Group in the 2nd and in the 3rd case, it could be useful a general theorem about the n-th root of 1.

**Theorem** If $\zeta_n$ is a $n$-nt root of 1, then $Gal \left(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}\right) \simeq \left(\mathbb{Z}_n\right)^*$

If I well remember, You can try to prove it observing that an automorphism sends a primitive root in a primitive root.

So, in the remaining cases, our Galois Groups are:

$Gal \left(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{10}):\mathbb{Q}\right) \simeq \left(\mathbb{Z}_{10}\right)^* \simeq \mathbb{Z}_4$

$Gal \left(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8):\mathbb{Q}\right) \simeq \left(\mathbb{Z}_8\right)^* \simeq \mathbb{Z}_4$

Comment: Your solutions for the second and third case make sense, however, I would like to get in the habit of putting them in the form like you did for the first one, which is similar to how I approached it. Would you be able to? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I think you can easy find an automorphism, in the 2nd and 3rd cases, of order 4. Then the Galois groups must be cyclic and have order 4 (because each extension has degree 4). Then they are isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}_4$